# what can i do to make my add to cart button work?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Please help me out, i'm working on an e-commerce site, I added a category page, on the index page the add to cart works but when I select a particular category, and I try to add any of the product, it doesn't add to the cart and it goes back to the index page, and untick the category, maybe someone can assist me here is my code below:
I have three files,
this is my index codes

index.php:

```
<!--= this code displays the categories -->
<h3 class="text-center text-light bg-dark p-2"><b><a style="color: white;" href="index.php">Products</a></b></h3>

`enter code here`<div class="container-fluid">
    enter code here<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <h3 class="text-center"><b>All Categories</b></h3>
            <hr>
            <h6 class="text-light bg-dark p-2 rounded"><b>Select Category</b></h6>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT product_cat FROM products ORDER BY product_cat";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){    
                ?>

                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input product_check" value="<?= $row['product_cat']; ?>" id="product_cat"><?= $row['product_cat']; ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <h5 class="text-center" style="font-weight: bolder;" id="textChange">All Products</h5>
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="../images/loader.gif" id="loader" width="200" style="display: none;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="row" id="result">


                <div id="message"></div>
            <div class="row mt-2 pb-3">

                <?php

                    include 'config.php';
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM products";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
                ?>
                
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-2">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card p-2 border-secondary mb-2">

                    <img src="../admin/product-images/<?= $row['product_image']; ?>" class="card-img-top" height="250">

                    <div class="card-body p-1">
                        <h4 class="card-title text-center text-info"><?= $row['product_name'] ?></h4>

                        <h5 class="card-text text-center text-danger"><b>₦ <?= number_format($row['product_price'],2) ?>/- </b></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer p-1">
                        <form action="" class="form-submit">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?= $row['product_name'] ?>">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="<?= $row['product_price'] ?>">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pimage" value="<?= $row['product_image'] ?>">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pcode" value="<?= $row['product_code'] ?>">

                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block addItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add to Cart</button>

                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block viewItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;View Details</button>

                        </form>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            
        
    </div>
</div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){


            $(".addItemBtn").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form = $(this).closest(".form-submit");
                var pid = $form.find(".pid").val();
                var pname = $form.find(".pname").val();
                var pprice = $form.find(".pprice").val();
                var pimage = $form.find(".pimage").val();
                var pcode = $form.find(".pcode").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'action.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {pid:pid,pname:pname,pprice:pprice,pimage:pimage,pcode:pcode},
                    success:function(response){
                        $("#message").html(response);
                        load_cart_item_number();
                    }
                });
            });


            load_cart_item_number();

            function load_cart_item_number(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../action.php',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {cartItem:"cart_item"},
                    success:function(response){
                        $("#cart-item").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }


            $(".product_check").click(function(){
                $("#loader").show();

                var action = 'data';
                var product_cat = get_filter_text('product_cat');

                $.ajax({
                    url:'action.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{action:action,product_cat:product_cat},
                    success:function(response){
                        $("#result").html(response);
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        $("#textChange").text("Filtered Products");
                    }
                });
            });
            
            function get_filter_text(text_id){
                var filterData = [];
                $('#'+text_id+':checked').each(function(){
                    filterData.push($(this).val());
                });
                return filterData;
            }







        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my action codes

action.php:

```
<?php
//db connection
require 'config.php';

//display products and category products
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_cat !=''";

    if (isset($_POST['product_cat'])) {
        $product_cat = implode("','", $_POST['product_cat']);
        $sql .="AND product_cat IN('".$product_cat."')";
    }
    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $output='';

    if($result->num_rows>0){
        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $output .= '<div id="message"></div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-2">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card p-2 border-secondary mb-2">

                    <img src="../admin/product-images/'.$row['product_image'].'" class="card-img-top" height="250">

                    <div class="card-body p-1">
                        <h4 class="card-title text-center text-info">'.$row['product_name'].'</h4>

                        <h5 class="card-text text-center text-danger"><b>₦ '.number_format($row['product_price'],2).'/- </b></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer p-1">
                        <form action="" class="form-submit">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="'.$row['id'].'">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="'.$row['product_name'].'">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="'.$row['product_price'].'">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pimage" value="'.$row['product_image'].'">

                            <input type="hidden" class="pcode" value="'.$row['product_code'].'">

                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block addItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-cart- 
                            plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add to Cart</button>

                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block viewItemBtn"><i class="fas fa-info- 
                            circle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;View Details</button>

                        </form>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
        }
    }
    else{
        $output = "<h3>No Products Found!</h3>";
    }
    echo $output;

    }

//add to cart codes
    if(isset($_POST['pid'])){
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $pname = $_POST['pname'];
    $pprice = $_POST['pprice'];
    $pimage = $_POST['pimage'];
    $pcode = $_POST['pcode'];
    $pqty = 1;


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_code FROM cart WHERE product_code=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$pcode);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    $r = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $code = $r['product_code'];

    if(!$code){
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (product_name,product_price,product_image,qty,total_price,product_code) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $query->bind_param("sssiss",$pname,$pprice,$pimage,$pqty,$pprice,$pcode);
        $query->execute();

        echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismisible mt-2">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Item added to your cart!</strong>
        </div>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismisible mt-2">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Item already added to your cart!</strong>
        </div>';
    }
}

?>
```

thank you

Comment: Set `action=""` to `action="action.php"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but in which file should i change, is it in both files or only the one in action.php? Thanks

Comment: I have set my action=" " to action="action.php" it didn't work. And @B001, please where should i store it?